# AxiosError: Network Error in React Native only IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I am using redux in my application and using Axios to call APIs but somehow API returning [AxiosError: Network Error] this msg and it is only showing in IOS, in android works fine
I already tried many solutions on info.plist file please help me!
I tried to to add  in dict tag but no luck
mostly my signin and signupaction are not working

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>exthoarding</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>http://65.0.108.81/hoarding/</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>yourserver.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your camera to take photos.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your photo library to save photos.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your photo library to select photos.</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Lato-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-SemiBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Poppins-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Poppins-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>DMSans_18pt-Medium.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add the following to plist.info, which disables all app transport security restrictions and should allow you to connect via HTTP:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```